# repetition of naming both the transaction and the object store

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

Specifying the name of the "table" in the [Object Store](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBObjectStore) method seems repetitive if the transaction is for only 1 "table".

Q: Is there a way to reduce the repetition of:

```
var transaction = db.transaction(["toDoList"], "readwrite");
var objectStore = transaction.objectStore("toDoList");
```

Comment: Store the name in a variable? Or are you asking if there is some more concise way of using the API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason there is repetition is that you can open a transaction on multiple object stores. If you are commonly just opening a transaction on one object store, you could wrap it in a function:

```
function getObjectStore(name) {
    var transaction = db.transaction([name], "readwrite");
    return transaction.objectStore(name);    
}

var objectStore = getObjectStore("toDoList");
```

More generally, the entire IndexedDB API is rather verbose and it's more pleasant to use a wrapper library like http://dexie.org/ or https://github.com/jakearchibald/idb